# select specific rows by row number in sas

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS I have SAS data like (It does not contain Obs column)

```
Obs    ID    Name    Score1    Score2    Score3

1     101               90        95        98
2     203               78        77        75
3     223               88        67        75
4     280               68        87        75
.
.
.
.
100   468               78        77        75
```

I want data having row number 2 6 8 10 34. Output should look like

```
Obs    ID    Name    Score1    Score2    Score3

1     203               78        77        75
2     227               88        67        75
3     280               68        87        75
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop through each line of data with a data step and only output the lines when you are in the n'th loop with a condition like this.

```
data test;
    set LIB.TABLE;
    if _N_ in (2, 6, 8, 10, 34) then output;
    run;
```

where `_N_` will correspond to the number of the line in this case.

Comment: Since OP is new to SAS, it's worth pointing out that _n_ is NOT actually a row number.  It's a counter of the number of times the data step has iterated.  People often use it as a row number in simple data steps like this.  Just good to know that it's not really a row number, in more complex data steps _N_ may not correspond at all to data step row number.

Comment: An answer containing only code is not a good answer.  Please explain how the code works and include any information necessary to correctly use the code in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is ok for small tables, but if you are working with a very large table it's inefficient as it reads every row in the table to see whether it has the right row number. Here's a more direct approach:

```
data example;
    do i = 2, 6, 8, 10;
        set sashelp.class point = i;
        output;
    end;
    stop;
run;
```

This picks out just the rows you actually want and doesn't read all the others.

Comment: As the OP is a newbie to SAS, it's probably worth mentioning the importance of the `stop` statement.  Because SAS is directly accessing the specific records, it won't read the end of file marker that normally ends a query automatically.  Without `stop` the query would never end.

Comment: @D.O. the only way to do that would be to use data set options - e.g. `select * from mytable(obs=n firstobs=n)` to get row `n`. SQL itself has no concept of row numbers.